# How do we say hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

When speaking series of decimal numbers, we say "one... nine, ten"; when speaking hexadecimals do we say "one... e, f, ten"? Do we say "nineteen, **a**teen, **b**teen... **f**teen, twenty" and so forth, or do we say "one-a, one-b" etc?
On that note, would 10 be spoken "ten" or "one-zero"?

Comment: Would this help? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52494/

Comment: Well done for finding that @Rex. If better answers are required than the ones there, then that question is the place to put them.