# Is there a naming pattern that can be applied to numbers in another radix/base/root?

Tags: vocabulary

In decimal (Base Ten), we have one, two... ten... twenty-five, etc.

In senary (Base Six), what would we call six (written "10" in senary)?

What would we call the hundredths position of a senary number (12_45)?
What would we call the thousandths position (1_345)?

Is there a linguistic pattern that can be applied to this?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for Math Stack Exchange. Not many would understand that kind of jargon hereabouts, I'm afraid.

Comment: For the first question, I would say "one zero, base 6." See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52494/how-do-you-pronounce-numbers-written-in-different-bases .

Comment: For the second question, I would call it the "36ths position" and the "216ths position," analogous to the hundredths and thousandths positions.

Comment: Why was this question closed because of [this other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400058/a-term-for-radix-point-that-everyone-would-understand)? The other question asked about decimal separators, and any alternative terms for it. It should've been closed for [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52494/how-do-you-pronounce-numbers-written-in-different-bases).

Comment: @rajah9 Great find.. I duplicated that question! Surprised it didn't come up when I first searched... and it's ashame there's not a pattern available for this like we have for units with the metric system.

Comment: If humans had three fingers on each hand, then perhaps we would have a corresponding linguistic pattern. The Babylonians had a system based on 60, so we have hours, minutes, and seconds (and degrees/minutes/seconds)

Comment: @rajah9 Interestingly, there is a group of humans that counted by six due to an abundance of yams. When placed on the ground, it takes 6 to make a circle. It's also very intuitive for counting with positional numerals since we have 5 fingers. 5 fingers + the concept of 0 gives you 6 digits. So, one hand is the tens digit and the other is the ones digit, so you can count easily to 36 using your full fingers.

Comment: Perhaps the solution is really to leverage the native language of other cultures (which I believe English is known for as-is)... The Komnzo language goes up to at least 6^6.